# How to play a video with any video format into HTML5 ( previously played using Flash)

Tags: javascript, java, flash, html5-video, freemarker

The problem faced is that when there is an input of a video (any video in any format), the web will play the video using flash technology. However, flash technology is no longer used and the video input will be played using HTML5. I'm stuck in this code and here is the code

This is a webscript for html5

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
   new Alfresco.dashlet.VideoWidget("${args.htmlid}").setOptions(
   {
      "componentId": "${instance.object.id}",
      "site": "${page.url.templateArgs.site!""}", 
      "nodeRef": "<#if args.nodeRef?exists>${args.nodeRef}<#else></#if>", 
      "name": "<#if node??>${node.name}</#if>",
      "title": "<#if node??>${node.title}</#if>"
   }).setMessages(${messages});
   <#if node??>
   new Alfresco.VideoPreview("${args.htmlid}-preview").setOptions(
   {
      nodeRef: "${args.nodeRef}",
      name: "${node.name?js_string}",
      icon: "${node.icon}",
      mimeType: "${node.mimeType}",
      previews: [<#list node.previews as p>"${p}"<#if (p_has_next)>, </#if></#list>],
      availablePreviews: [<#list node.generatedPreviews as p>"${p.thumbnailName}"<#if (p_has_next)>, </#if></#list>],
      size: "${node.size}"
   }).setMessages(
      ${messages}
         );
   </#if>
   new Alfresco.widget.DashletResizer("${args.htmlid}", "${instance.object.id}");
//]]></script>
<div class="dashlet video">
   <div class="title"><#if node??>${node.title!node.name}<#else>${msg("header.video")}</#if></div>
   <div class="toolbar">
      <a id="${args.htmlid}-configVideo-link" href="#" class="theme-color-1">${msg("link.configure")}</a>
   </div>
   <div class="body" id="${args.htmlid}-body" style="height: ${args.height!200}px;">
      <div class="msg video-widget-msg" id="${args.htmlid}-msg"></div>
      <div class="video-preview shadow" id="${args.htmlid}-preview" style="height: ${args.height!200}px;">
         <div class="bd">
            <div id="${args.htmlid}-preview-shadow-swf-div" class="preview-swf">
               <div id="${args.htmlid}-preview-swfPlayerMessage-div">${msg("label.preparingPreviewer")}</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Voting to close the question as unclear. Basically OP wants to "do something" and has "a problem", we can't answer this question as it is now. Please edit your question and state a clear problem.

Comment: Your shown code doesn't help us to recreate your problem.  You ask about Flash video but you do not have any video FLV files in your code. Maybe you have a Flash app (.SWF file) that loads a video? In such a case find the FLV video or MP4 video that it loads.

Comment: can you help me to understand that code? this is really new to me, this is totally out of my league. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't know what needs to be understood. I don't use Alfresco but it seems to be adding 3 widgets and then a bunch of `<div>` containers. You need to create a `<video>` tag within one of those Divs and give it an MP4 video file link. That will play video without using Flash plugin.